# Select a list of KeyValuePairs from BindingList<KeyValuePair<string, string> where the key or the value match some comparision criteria

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am dabbling with LINQ (and using lambdas)..

I have:

```
BindingList<KeyValuePair<string, string> bList = new BindingList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

string keyX = sometext1;
string valueX = sometext2;
```

I need to find the entries in bList which have, either the key same as keyX; or the value same as valueX.

I attempted something like this..

```
bList.Select(xy => {string.Compare(xy.Key, keyX, true) == 0 || string.Compare(xy.Value, valueX, true)}).ToList()
```

I am pretty sure, I have to use some kind of a "where" operator, but I could not find the syntax for that.. Plz correct me where I'm wrong.

Comment: Just switch your `Select` for a `Where` (literally just the text) and don't forget a second `== 0` and it looks like it should work.

Comment: well, walther I got to know that LINQ extended the C# syntax and functionality to contain a where operator. Just didn't know where to use it, or how. I didn't think its a duplicate. Well, if you say so.. 

Thanks Rawling and Douglas.

Comment: @user1079159 so you should probably read some Tutorials about LinQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace your `Select` with a `Where` (and make some other minor adjustments to your lambda expression):

```
bList.Where(xy => string.Compare(xy.Key, keyX, true) == 0 || 
                  string.Compare(xy.Value, valueX, true) == 0)
     .ToList()
```

Your code would be more efficient if you used `String.Equals`, instead of `String.Compare`, to perform equality comparisons.

```
bList.Where(xy => string.Equals(xy.Key, keyX, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) || 
                  string.Equals(xy.Value, valueX, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
     .ToList()
```

`CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` specifies a case-insensitive comparison (similar to what is performed in `string.Compare(s1, s2, true)`).

Comment: @Rawling: You're right. And it also had a redundant pair of curly braces (presumably to match the type inferred by the `Select`).